# How do I animate an element to move diagonally without translateX and translateY?

Tags: javascript, css

I'm trying to make this animation move more smoothly. I tried this using 'transform: translateX() translateY()' and I got the result I wanted, but I would like to use top/left instead because I want to be able to repeat the animation with bottom/right and be able to use the same measurements.

https://jsfiddle.net/jyozy12a/

```
@keyframes field10 {
    from{
        left: 201px;
    }
    to{
        left: 639px;
        top: 240px;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set the element `css` starting position equal to `@keyframes` rules starting position; that is `left:201px`, `top:0px`

```
.card-o {
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-radius: 2px;
  position: absolute;
  width: 160px; 
  height: 200px;
  left:201px;
  top:0px;
}
```

jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/jyozy12a/1/

Comment: @NickDuto Alternatively, setting element `left:0px` https://jsfiddle.net/jyozy12a/2/ ; you could also set `left:0px` at `from` declatation within `@keyframes`